# If condition is getting skipped even if the condition is true

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, if-statement

I am using an If statement inside a for loop but the If statement is getting skipped even after the condition is met

```
x=raw_input().split(" ")  
c=[]  
for a in x:  
    b=1  
    if a<0:  
        print "Please enter a number greater than or equal to 0"  
    else:      
        if(a==1 or a==0 ):  
            print "1"  
    for i in range(1,int(a)+1):  
            b=b*i  
    c.append(str(b))  

print ",".join(c)
```

the program is to find factorial, i am getting the result. If someone enters a negative number, it should not return a factorial but this does. I just want to know why is the if and else conditions getting skipped.

Comment: Good to hear - Also please add continue in the code. then it will skip calculating facotrial for negative number

Comment: At this stage you really should not be devoting effort to learning Python 2. Please consider installing and learning Python 3 instead. Support for Python 2 ceases on 1 January.

Comment: I have enrolled for a course and isn't there only a minor difference between python 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing **string** with **number** returns `False` as result

```
'-2'< 0 ---> False --> if condition will be skipped
```

Convert the **string** to **integer** since factorial are only applied to integer

```
int('-2') < 0 ---> True --> if condition will be executed
```

- `x = raw_input().split(" ")`  returns **strings data type in a list**
- so you can't use `int` for the entire list `x`,
- only one string at the time

When invoking the if condition you are considering only one element in the list,

```
then convert from string to int before comparing to 0 --> int(a) < 0
```

---

> The second point is related to **indentation** `print (",".join(c))`
> should be included inside the `else` loop

Also

```
if(a==1 or a==0 ):  
                print "1"
```

is not needed as it has been take care in the for loop below

## The code is as follow

```
x=raw_input().split(" ")  
c=[]  
for a in x:  
    b=1  
    if int(a) < 0:  
        print "Please enter a number greater than or equal to 0"  
    else:      
        for i in range(1,int(a)+1):  
            b=b*i  
        c.append(str(b))  
        

        print ",".join(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to convert the input into int before doing int operations. Change this

```
x=raw_input().split(" ")
```

to

```
x=map(int, raw_input().split(" "))
```

Comment: but i think this will still calculate the facotrial for negative numbers in the SO code.

Comment: This if `if a<0:` is getting skipped.

Comment: but in the question - for loop is outside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
x="-2 3 6 -3".split(" ") 
c=[]  
for a in x:  
    b=1  
    if int(a)<0:  
        print ("Please enter a number greater than or equal to 0" ) 
        continue
    else:      
        if(a==1 or a==0 ):  
            print ("1"  )
    for i in range(1,int(a)+1):  
            b=b*i  
    c.append(str(b))  

print (",".join(c))
```

o/p:

```
Please enter a number greater than or equal to 0
Please enter a number greater than or equal to 0
6,720
```

Two changes, `int(a)` in if condition and if you wish not to calculate the factorial for negative numbers then add `continue`